# How can I extend an embedded python interpreter with C++ functions?

Tags: python, boost, embed, extend, boost-python

How can I extend an embedded interpreter with C++ code? I have embedded the interpreter and I can use boost.python to make a loadable module (as in a shared library) but I don't want the library floating around because I want to directly interface with my C++ application. Sorry if my writing is a bit incoherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for the 2.x interpreters: you write your methods as C-style code with PyObject* return values.  They all basically look like:

```
PyObject* foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
```

Then, you collect these methods in a static array of PyMethodDef:

```
static PyMethodDef MyMethods[] =
{
    {"mymethod", foo, METH_VARARGS, "What my method does"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

Then, after you've created and initialized the interpreter, you can add these methods "into" the interpreter via the following:

```
Py_InitModule("modulename", MyMethods);
```

You can refer now to your methods via the modulename you've declared here.

Some additional info here:
http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~awinsl02/py_c/

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at this kind of stuff for ages, it just didn't seem like what I wanted. Now that you've put it like this my puny mind can understand! Thank you!